# sp_executesql for excuting the queries which are stored in another table and results will store in another table

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have two table.

TableA:

| EmpID | Query |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | select count(*) from emplyee where emp_no != null; |
| 2 | select count(*) from dept where dept_id ! = null; |

I am writing the stored procedure to handle this process like below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ExecuteAndStoreDynamicQueriesWithId
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @query_id INT;

    -- Declare variables for query result and ID column
    DECLARE @query_result NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @result_id INT;

    -- Declare a cursor to loop through the query_table
    DECLARE @curQuery CURSOR;
    SET @curQuery = CURSOR FOR SELECT sql_query, query_id FROM query_table;

    OPEN @curQuery;

    FETCH NEXT FROM @curQuery INTO @query, @query_id;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        -- Execute the dynamic query and store result
print 'Query is '+@query
        EXEC sp_executesql @query, N'@result NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', @result = @query_result OUTPUT;
print 'Result  is '+@query_result
        -- Insert the result along with the ID into result_table
        INSERT INTO result_table (query_id, query_result)
        VALUES (@query_id, @query_result);

        FETCH NEXT FROM @curQuery INTO @query, @query_id;
    END;

    CLOSE @curQuery;
    DEALLOCATE @curQuery;
END;
```

But the issue is my Target table TableB is loaded with only query_id and query_result is coming as null values after executing the procedure.
I can see Query print and am not able to see Result print.

Any clue would be appreciated...

Thank you.

I am expecting the target table should be like below by running the actual queries from TableA.

| EmpID | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 |
| 2 | 45 |

Now I am getting output like the below,

| EmpID | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | null |

Comment: Cursors are a code-smell, I think you should be able to use `sp_executesql` with `CROSS APPLY` here instead.

Comment: without cursors how can I loop the rows from tableA?

Comment: Are **all** the queries in `TableA.Query` scalar (1-row, 1-column) queries - or can any of them return multiple rows and/or columns?

Comment: Queries output will be a single value.